# React Native- How to prevent "SignIn" AND "Signup" buttons from showing ActivityIndicator at same time

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making a login screen where a user can Sign In and Sign Up for an account. When the user clicks one of these buttons, I would like for the ActivityIndicator to take it's place while it loads. However, when I press Sign In, both buttons disappear and show the indicator and vice versa. It's like they're being clicked together. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input, Spinner, renderIfElse } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        message: '',
        color: '',
        loggedIn: false,
        loading: false
    };

    this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
    this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);
}

//Dynamically changes the style of the "this.state.message" text below
getMessageStyle() {
    return {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: this.state.color,
        alignSelf: 'center'
    };
}

signIn() {
    const { email, password } = this.state; //refactors out the user and pass out of state

    this.setState({
        message: '', //resets the message to clear
        loading: true
    });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {       //If user found, sign them in
            this.setState({
                color: 'green',
                message: 'Signed In',
                loggedIn: true,
                loading: false
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {      //If user not found
            this.setState({
                color: 'red',
                message: 'Account Not Found',
                loggedIn: false,
                loading: false
            });
        });
}

signUp() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        message: '',
        loading: true
    });

    if (email === '' && password === '') {
        this.setState({
            color: 'red',
            message: 'Enter email and password!',
            loading: false
        });
        return;
    } else if (email === '') {
        this.setState({
            color: 'red',
            message: 'Enter email!',
            loading: false
        });
        return;
    } else if (password === '') {
        this.setState({
            color: 'red',
            message: 'Enter password!',
            loading: false
        });
        return;
    }


    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {       //Sign Up a user successfully
            this.setState({
                color: 'green',
                message: 'User created!',
                loggedIn: true,
                loading: false
            });
        })
        .catch(() => {      //Sign Up failed for some reason
            this.setState({
                color: 'red',
                message: 'Signup failed!',
                loggedIn: false,
                loading: false
            });
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection>
                <Input
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                    label='Email'
                    placeholder='user@gmail.com'
                />
            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>
                <Input
                    secureTextEntry
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                    label='Password'
                    placeholder='password'
                />
            </CardSection>

            <Text style={this.getMessageStyle()}>{this.state.message}</Text>

            <CardSection>
                {renderIfElse(
                    this.state.loading,
                    <Spinner size='small' />,
                    <Button onPress={this.signIn}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                )}
                {this.state.loggedIn && <Button >
                    Logout
                </Button>}
            </CardSection>
            <CardSection>
                {renderIfElse(
                    this.state.loading,
                    <Spinner size='small' />,
                    <Button onPress={this.signUp}>
                        Sign Up
                    </Button>
                )}
            </CardSection>
        </Card>
    );
}
}

export default LoginForm;
```

And here is my renderIfElse code:

```
function renderIfElse(condition, content1, content2) {
if (condition) {
    return content1;
} else if (!condition) {
    return content2;
}
}

export default renderIfElse;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using the same state value to determine whether to render the `ActivityIndicator` instead of the button, in both cases. In other words, when you tap the Sign In button, you change the `loading` state to `true`, which causes *both* buttons to render the `ActivityIndicator`, since that variable is what they are using to determine how to render.

There are several ways you could fix this. One would be to use more than one state value to determine what is being loaded. For example, instead of using `loading`, you could use `loadingSignIn` and `loadingSignUp`, like this:

```
    <CardSection>
        {renderIfElse(
            this.state.loadingSignIn,
            <Spinner size='small' />,
            <Button onPress={this.signIn}>
                Login
            </Button>
        )}
        {this.state.loggedIn && <Button >
            Logout
        </Button>}
    </CardSection>
    <CardSection>
        {renderIfElse(
            this.state.loadingSignUp,
            <Spinner size='small' />,
            <Button onPress={this.signUp}>
                Sign Up
            </Button>
        )}
    </CardSection>
```

Of course, you'd have to update the rest of the code to account for there being two `loading` states instead of one, but that shouldn't be too difficult and will fix the issue.

Comment: I had just actually figured out my question right after I left the house (half of it at least). But I left it because I thought maybe there would be a less silly way to fix it than to have to have 2 states, but I was wrong. I'd assume there are a lot of instances where people have to deal with this issue. It would be nice  to be able to bind each button to state, and the language know that we want only one to change. Meh. Thank you dbburgess.

While I have you on here, totally unrelated, earlier a fetch function was calling itself each load. Why did binding itself to "this" fix it?

Comment: Well, there *are* other approaches or fixes rather than just two states...That's just a rather simple, straightforward one. As for your question related to `this`, if I understand correctly, these docs may be helpful: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html -- *"In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called. This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript."* There are some helpful links there, as well.